# How to Save the data in Page using C#

Tags: c#

I am working one portal where user can login and will enter his details and later he can view those details after login again. But unfortunately data is not not displaying in page. Here is I am giving everything which I did.

**Code** Explanation:

This is the Button code for data in database.

```
 protected void btnContactInfoSave_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chkContactUpdate.Checked)
            {
                string[] ContactInfoData = new string[6];
                ContactInfoData[0] = GlobalVars.UserEmail;
                ContactInfoData[1] = txtCnct.Text;
                ContactInfoData[2] = txtAltCnct.Text;
                ContactInfoData[3] = txtEmrCnct.Text;
                ContactInfoData[4] = txtPrsnEmail.Text;
                ContactInfoData[5] = txtOfsEmail.Text;
                Utilities.sqlUploadContactInfoData(ContactInfoData);
            }
            else
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Error", "alert('Please click on the checkbox before Saving.');", true);
            }
        }
```

Here is the code for the Button creation :

When user clicks this button data should be added in database. wat ever the data user enters it has to save in database.

Code for uploading the data in database.

```
public static void sqlUploadContactInfoData(string[] Userdata) // code for saving the data in database
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlConn = PortalDBConnection())
            {
                try
                {
                    sqlConn.Open();
                    string spName = "sp_testSample";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(spName, sqlConn);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CnctNum", Userdata[1].ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AltCnctNum", Userdata[2].ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmerCnctNum", Userdata[3].ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrsnEmail", Userdata[4].ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OfsEmail", Userdata[5].ToString());
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (SqlException)
                {
                    ErrorMsg("Server Error", "Server Error ! Please try again Later.");
                }
            }
        }
```

Here I have a problem that I am unable to display the data in page.
When user clicks the button, data is saving in database. The problem is when user login and fill the data and he can save the data. once he logged out from portal and after login again data is not displaying there. Data need to save in page also.

Any problem in above code..??

Comment: You should fetch data from database and bind to UI controls (e.g. TextBox) when user comes to page

Comment: @kostbone yeah I agree you. He should fetch the data and bind to UI you can't save the data in to page.

Answer (score -1):

```
        string strCnctNum = txtCnctNum.Text;
        //Then reset your control like below
        `txtCnctNum.Text = "";
         txtAltCnctNum.Text = "";
         ...
         etc
        // Then Use This Code to To Retrieve & Display Data
        using (SqlConnection oSqlConnection = new SqlConnection("YourConnectionString"))
        {
            string strCommand = "Select * from YourTableName where CnctNum="+ strCnctNum +";
            SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand(strCommand, oSqlConnection);
            oSqlConnection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader oReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (oReader.Read())
                {
                    txtCnctNum.Text = oReader["CnctNum"].ToString();
                    txtAltCnctNum.Text = oReader["AltCnct"].ToString();
                    .....
                    etc
                }

                oSqlConnection.Close();
            }
        }`
```